# how to create a view from another database in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to create a view in a database called "**Database2**" from the collection "**Database1**". I'm using the query:

```
db.createView(<view>, <source>, <pipeline>, <options>)
```

and converting it into:

```
db.createView("**view_1**", "**Database1.Table1**", <pipeline>, <options>)
```

I'm executing it within **Database2**, it creates a view but it does not have any data in it.

How can I get ti to work?

Comment: As at MongoDB 3.6, a view has to be created in the same database as the source collection.

Comment: @Stennie Oh ok. Thank You, Stennie. I wanted to cgive acces to subset of a view for different companies based on their id. How can I do that. Do you know any tool to make this work? Thank You in Advance!

Comment: The `source` for a view can either be a collection or a view, so you could create a subset as long as the source collections/views are in the same database. You could also use [collection-level access control](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/collection-level-access-control/) to limit access to customer views. However, I expect your customers would normally be accessing data from an API rather than directly querying your MongoDB deployment. Can you describe the use case in a bit more detail: are these views for your application to use or for direct users of your MongoDB deployment?

Comment: @Stennie We are using a tool called Metabase and it connects with our db and user can create their pwn view anytime. The idea is that every customer/partner can have access to their data to query or build graphs as they seem fit with their data. We want allow only certain views to be exposed instead of the entire db that we have. Basically, we want to handle it using a configuration rather than an api. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Metabase or how it integrates with MongoDB. I would ask on the [Metabase forums](http://discourse.metabase.com/) (if you haven't already) and include a link to that discussion here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Mongo 4.2, you cannot create views across databases. The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createView/) for views states the following:

*The name of the source collection or view from which to create the view. The name is not the full namespace of the collection or view; i.e. does not include the database name and implies the same database as the view to create. **You must create views in the same database as the source collection**.*